# Taking advantage of sample data provided in text format

Tags: discussion

In many questions regarding databases OPs are encouraged by the community to provide sample data for the
tables in a text format.

However, everybody provides their own version of the text format.

I wonder how this provided text can be utilised **easily** by the replying parties for reproducing OPs tables or data

e.g. generating `insert` or `with` clauses?

Comment: On a question where the data dump is 4 lines long. 
My take is if the data dump is simple enough to represent a table in excel after a simple copy past( not mannually tabulated data, but consitent tabulation/seprator). The generation of the DDL + DML is a simple copy past on http://sqlfiddle.com/ with the [ Text to DDL ] button.

But if the data are more than 3 tables with less than 5 rows. Not having a DDL or Cte with declaration can be a pain.

Comment: @DragandDrop thanks for the "Text to DDL" button tip - wasn't aware of its existence...